# Generating compilation database for a single target with cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm using `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` variable of `cmake` to obtain a json compilation database that I can then parse to identify the options that are given to the compiler for each source file. Now, the project I'm working on has several targets, and there are several occurrences of the source files that are used in different targets in the database, as can be shown by the example below:

`f.c`:

```c
int main () { return MACRO; }
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Test)
add_executable(test1 f.c)
add_executable(test2 f.c)
target_compile_options(test1 PUBLIC -DMACRO=1)
target_compile_options(test2 PUBLIC -DMACRO=2)
```

running `cmake . -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1` will produce the following `compile-commands.json` file, with two entries for `f.c`, and no easy way to distinguish between them.

```js
[
{
  "directory": "/home/virgile/tmp/cmakefile",
  "command": "/usr/bin/cc     -DMACRO=1 -o CMakeFiles/test1.dir/f.c.o   -c /home/virgile/tmp/cmakefile/f.c",
  "file": "/home/virgile/tmp/cmakefile/f.c"
},
{
  "directory": "/home/virgile/tmp/cmakefile",
  "command": "/usr/bin/cc     -DMACRO=2 -o CMakeFiles/test2.dir/f.c.o   -c /home/virgile/tmp/cmakefile/f.c",
  "file": "/home/virgile/tmp/cmakefile/f.c"
}
]
```

I'm looking for a way to specify that I'm only interested in e.g. target `test1`, as what you can do in build tool mode with `--target`, preferably without having to modify `CMakeLists.txt`, but this is not a major issue. What I'd like to avoid, on the other hand, is to read the argument of `-o` in the `"command"` entry and discriminate between the `test1.dir` and `test2.dir` path component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently this feature has been implemented in a merge-request about 3 months ago: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/5651

From there I quote:

> The new target property EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS associated with the
> existing global variable can be used to optionally configure targets for
> their compile commands to be exported.

So it seems that you now can set a property on the respective targets in order to control whether or not they will be included in the generated DB.

---

This feature is part of cmake 3.20. Official docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html

---

Based on the docs the approach for limiting the compile DB to only a specific target should be to set `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` to `OFF` and then use `target_set_properties` to set the `EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` property on the desired target to `ON`. E.g.

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS OFF)
...
set_target_properties(test1 PROPERTIES EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually explain how to either get separate compilation_commands.json files per target, or discern specific targets within the compilation_commands.json file.

Comment: @Matt that's also not what has been asked by OP. The question is focused on restricting the entries in the generated file to a specific target. That's what I answered.

Comment: Let me paraphrase what I'm saying, OP is saying "I'm looking for a way to specify that I'm only interested in e.g. target test1".   If you take the EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS and use it with cmake 3.2 or newer (testing in 3.22.1), following OP's example CMakeLists.txt and add set_target_properties(test1 PROPERTIES EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS on), you still get a compilation_commands.json with compile commands representing BOTH targets. -- I'm really saying that instructions how to use this property to get desired output is missing.

Comment: @Matt gotcha. I've added a new paragraph to my answer that theoretically should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not supported at the moment. There is a request for this in the CMake issue tracker: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19462